# Can G+H be able access firebase realtime database on devices that supports only HMS

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, huawei-mobile-services

I'm trying to upload my app to app gallery i use firebase realtime database for my database management. I have integrated the HMS toolkit on Android studio to convert my codebase to support HMS. But I do not know if the conversion would still able Huawei devices to still be able to access my database, or if i can connect Huawei cloud dB to firebase to enable the device have access

I have implemented HMS toolkit to convert my codebase to support HMS, but I do not know if Huawei devices can assess firebase realtime database if the device does not support GMS

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.